# Periodically call deferToThread

Tags: python, twisted

I have a list of strings and I want to process the strings in a periodic manner.

The period of starting processing a new string is 1 second, and it takes 3 seconds to process a string.

What I expect to observe is that from the 3rd second on, I will see a new result every second until all the strings are processed.

However, what I actually saw was that all the results showed up together when all of them are generated.
So the question is, how to modify the code to achieve what I expect to see?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
import json
import time


def process(string):
    print "Processing " + string + "\n"
    time.sleep(3)  # simulate computation time

    # write result to file; result is mocked by string*3
    file_name = string + ".txt"
    with open(file_name, "w") as fp:
        json.dump(string*3, fp)

    print string + " processed\n"

string_list = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "XXXX", "YYYY", "ZZZZ"]

for s in string_list:
    # start a new thread every second
    time.sleep(1)
    threads.deferToThread(process, s)

reactor.run()
```

Meanwhile, it looks like that the order in which the results are generated isn't consistent with the order in which the strings are processed. I would guess it's just printed out of order but they actually are processed in order. How to verify my guess?

Another trivial thing I noticed is that `Processing YYYY` is not printed in the right place. Why is that? (There should be an empty line between it and the previous result.)

```
Processing AAAA

Processing BBBB

Processing CCCC

Processing XXXX
Processing YYYY


Processing ZZZZ

YYYY processed

CCCC processed

AAAA processed

BBBB processed

XXXX processed

ZZZZ processed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this part of your code does:

```
for s in string_list:
    # start a new thread every second
    time.sleep(1)
    threads.deferToThread(process, s)

reactor.run()
```

is schedule each chunk of work with a delay of one second between each scheduling operation.  Then, finally, it starts the reactor which allows processing to begin.  There is no processing until `reactor.run()`.

The use of `time.sleep(1)` also means your delays are blocking and this will be a problem once you solve the above.

One solution is to replace the `for` loop and the `time.sleep(1)` with a `LoopingCall`.

```
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall, react

string_list = [...]
def process(string):
    ...

def process_strings(the_strings, f):
    def dispatch(s):
        d = deferToThread(f, s)
        # Add callback / errback to d here to process the
        # result or report any problems.
        # Do _not_ return `d` though.  LoopingCall will
        # wait on it before running the next iteration if
        # we do.

    string_iter = iter(the_strings)
    c = LoopingCall(lambda: dispatch(next(string_iter)))
    d = c.start(1)
    d.addErrback(lambda err: err.trap(StopIteration))
    return d

def main(reactor):
    return process_strings(string_list, process)

react(main, [])
```

This code uses `react` to start and stop the reactor (it stops when the `Deferred` returned by `main` fires).  It uses `LoopingCall` started with a period of 1 to run `f(next(string_iter))` in the threadpool until `StopIteration` (or some other error) is encountered.

(`LoopingCall` and `deferToThread` both take `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass on to their callable so if you prefer (it's a matter of style), you can also write that expression as `LoopingCall(lambda: deferToThread(f, next(string_iter)))`.  You cannot "unwrap" the remaining lambda because that would result in `LoopingCall(deferToThread, f, next(string_iter))` which only evaluates `next(string_iter)` once at the time `LoopingCall` is called so you would end up processing the first string forever.)

There are other possible approaches to scheduling as well.  For example, you could use `cooperate` to run exactly 3 processing threads at a time - starting a new one as soon as an older one completes.

```
from twisted.internet.defer import gatherResults
from twisted.internet.task import cooperate

def process_strings(the_strings, f):
    # Define a generator of all of the jobs to be accomplished.
    work_iter = (
        deferToThread(lambda: f(a_string))
        for a_string
        in the_strings
    )
    # Consume jobs from the generator in parallel until done.
    tasks = list(cooperate(work_iter) for i in range(3))

    # Return a Deferred that fires when all three tasks have
    # finished consuming all available jobs.
    return gatherResults(list(
        t.whenDone()
        for t
        in tasks
    ))
```

In both cases, notice there's no use of `time.sleep`.

Comment: Can you please format the code that uses `cooperate`?

Comment: In your first solution, why the function to call of `LoopingCall` is `lambda: deferToThread()` instead of `deferToThread`?

Comment: The effect of running the first solution is that a string cannot start being processed until the previous one is processed. What I actually want is that a task can start even if there are unfinished tasks. (I haven't looked into the code of the second solution but by looking at the description it isn't what I want to see, since it claims "starting a new one as soon as an older one completes".)

Comment: deferToThread schedules into a threadpool.  If you want a very large number of tasks to be able to run concurrently, you may need to make the threadpool larger.  See IReactorThreads.

Comment: In my case, if I start a new task every second and it takes 3 seconds to process each task, then it will be only 3 concurrent tasks. I suggested the thread pool size to be 10 so there won't problems about thread pool overflowing.
However task B still starts after task A is finished. I thought that was due to the thread pool size was only 1 (could also be something else, this is just my worse guess), but after making it to be 10 explicitly the problem still isn't solved.

Comment: What I want to see is this sequence: `Processing A` (0 sec), `Processing B` (1 sec), `Processing C` (2 sec), `Processing X`/`A processed` (3 sec, A finishes at the same time when X starts). How to change the code to do that?

Comment: What does your actual processing function do?  Have you tried the LoopingCall solution with a dummy function that just sleeps?

Comment: Ah, nevermind that last question.  I see my mistake.  Editing answer.